# CSS Text positioning different in Safari for Heading tag

Tags: css

[image: text height]

Please see the attached image

This CSS is not producing the text to be lined up the same way in Safari and Firefox, and IE. Safari (on the right) is displaying about 2px higher.

```
h2{
font-size:18px;
color:#000;
display:inline-block;
font-family:Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
background-image:url(bkg.gif);
background-repeat:no-repeat;
padding-left:14px;
padding-top:4px;
height:28px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's how the browser renders text. If you're that concerned with it, serve up a stylesheet specifically for Safari and make the appropriate adjustments.